# Rmarkdown: add header under tabset

Tags: r, r-markdown

In Rmarkdown I use `{.tabset}` to split chunks into tabs:

```
# Tabset 1 {.tabset}    

## A    
Text under tab A

## B    
Text under tab B
```

I'd like to add a large header under some tabs:

```
# Tabset 1 {.tabset}

## A
Text under tab A

# Title that should be under tab A

## B
Text under tab B
```

But the single `#` gets interpreted as a new section and breaks up the tabbing:

[image]

Is there a way to add a header using `#`s without breaking the tabbing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution doesn't satisfy your "add a header using `#`s" requirement, but a workaround is to use HTML tags directly in your R markdown document:

```
<h1>Title that should be under tab A</h1>
```

The `<h1>` tag corresponds to the `#` level header and doesn't break the tabbing.