# Rmarkdown: remove some headers from TOC

Tags: r, r-markdown

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062672/rmarkdown-add-header-under-tabset/52063201#52063201). I'd like to put a header within a `{.tabset}` that does not get referenced by the TOC or break the tabbing. For example:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

# Tabset 1 {.tabset}

## A
Text under tab A

<h1>Don't want this in TOC</h1>

## B
Text under tab B
```

Produces this:

[image]

Is there anyway to format text like a header but not have it referenced in the TOC?

Comment: this issue deals with this: https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/318

Comment: maybe this post is of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138456/rmarkdown-with-knitr-to-html-how-to-hide-bullets-in-toc-table-of-contents

Comment: Why do you want it to be a header and not include it in the TOC? Or, do you just want it to be *formatted* like a header, but not behave like a header? PS There's a typo in your code: the closing header 1 tag should be `</h1>`.

Comment: Yes I just wanted it to be formatted like a header. I'll update to make that clear. The answer below does what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the comments there already seems to be an issue dealing with this particular problem.

However, a simple workaround would be to use a normal `<p>` tag but style it like a header. So for your particular example you could do the following:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

# Tabset 1 {.tabset}

## A
Text under tab A

<p style="font-weight:600; font-size:36px">Paragraph that looks like a header.</p>

## B
Text under tab B
```

According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) a value of 600 for font-weight qualifies as **semi-bold** which is what [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/) seems to be using for their `<h1>` headers.